# Nuget under Visual Studio 2012 fails when searching for packages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am behind a corporate firewall. However if I go straight to the PowerShell

```
Install-Package ReactiveUI
```

there is no problem. If I open the package manager and click on 'online' I can browse all the online packages from codeplex.

However as soon as I enter a search term in the package manager. I get the following error

```
Could not connect to the feed specified at 'https://nuget.org/api/v2'. 
Please verify that the package source ( located in the Package Manager Settings) 
is valid and ensure your network connectivity.
```

After I get this error the first time then Nuget fails to work even at the console.

Comment: Having lunch seems to work. I came back after a nice roll with ham and cheese sit down at my computer and it starts working

Comment: And about an hour later it starts playing up again?

Comment: I've seen this too. Any updates? Its quite annoying.

Comment: This is happening to me right now. No known solution?